# How to remove a ViewController from navigation stack and not have the option to go back to it-Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Login page and if the login is successful the user is taken to a landing viewController(VC).  I have a navigationController.  I pop the login VC and push in the landing VC.  The problem I am having is that the login VC persists in the stack as indicated by the left button on the navigation controller which navigates you back to the login page.  How do I remove the login VC copletely from the stack so that the navigation controller can not navigate a user back to it once they have logged in?

```
 self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

 let landingPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "landingPage") as! 
 LandingViewController

 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(landingPage, animated: true)
```

Comment: UINavigationController.viewControllers is the navigation stack you can remove one and set the array again to your NavigationController

Comment: could you eleborate?

Comment: check the answer provided by @Wez is that what I was talking about

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `setViewControllers` method to set the stack like this:

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([landingPage], animated: true)
```

You don't need to pop the login view controller first either.